# Nexus 7 incompatible

Tags: android, nexus-7

my app doesn't show up on the Nexus 7.

Here is my app manifest:

```
...<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="19" android:versionName="1.9" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.****.****" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  android:required="false" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"  android:required="false" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

...

Comment: Old Nexus 7 or the new 2013 edition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an old nexus 7, you have to add
 `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>`

Comment: There is no `android:required` attribute on a `<uses-permission>` element. You are perhaps thinking of `<uses-feature>`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: Currently I have: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>/ If I set it to false wont it will be a problem in other devices? Should I check to see if a camera is available at runtime before using it?

Comment: Yes. You have to check it programmatically if the camera is available. Also if you used only the back camera you should consider to use the front facing camera if the main camera is missing if the camera feature is a must for your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Old Nexus 7 you will have to add this to your manifest :

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: That is only true if the manifest has a `<compatible-screens>` element already.

Comment: Indeed but i am not sure that the Old Nexus 7 can be targeted with `<supports-screen>` since it is in tvdi density.

Comment: `<supports-screens>` has nothing to do with screen density. It does not constrain distribution by density, so all densities work.